# Detecting Object in an image with Python Pil

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, detect

I want to Detect objects in an image by using simple **python pil** codes.

For example Open an image and tell me how many objects are in the image but not too professional.

Can someone help?

Comment: Please post an example image and the expected output. Although, without using a computer vision lib it might turn out to be a lot of work!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think PIL/Pillow is the correct tool for this. I have successfully implemented object detection on images by using opencv (installing pyopencv and importing cv2). The install was not so straight forward, but once you are able to import cv2 then it is just a matter of calling [cv2.matchTemplate](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) with the correct parameters. Hope it helps.