# Can I use Pillow to find connected component?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am new to Pillow and I would like to learn how to use it.
I would like to seek your helps and expertise to suggest if I could use Pillow to find the connected component of an image?
For example, if I have an image such as the following
[image]

May I ask if I could use Pillow to give me the shapes and positions of my two components in my example ?  They are a square and a circle, and the circle is inside of the square.

Thank you very much,
Mi

Answer (score 0):

Using Pillow you can find the edges in the given image.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

image = Image.open("c1LDc.png")
image = image.convert('RGB')
imageWithEdges = image.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
image.show()
imageWithEdges.show()
```

Output:

[image]

You can't use Pillow for object detection, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004086/detecting-object-in-an-image-with-python-pil)

Comment: Thank you so much. I wonder if there is other software than opencv that could help me with object detection in an image? For example, using numpy and Pillow together may help to detect objects in an image ?

Comment: [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/), [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/), [keras](https://keras.io/), [theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/), [caffe](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/),